# Alfresco web-client-config-custom.xml override for guest in Explorer

Tags: customization, alfresco, explorer, web-client

Hi All i want to make some customization for alfresco web client "Explorer"
and i want to make this change only for guest user 
for example i want to make the landing page of the guest is 'guesthome'
i did this by adding to web-client-config-custom.xml

```
<config>
  <client>

     <!-- The default location to display when the browse screen is first shown -->
     <!-- This value should be one of 'myalfresco', 'userhome', 'companyhome' or 'guesthome' -->
     <initial-location>guesthome</initial-location>
  </client>
```

but the changes apply to every user how i can make this change available only for the guest user ? 
I user Alfresco Version :Community - v4.3.0 (r56867)
any help please

Comment: What Alfresco interface are you targetting - Share or Explorer? And what version of Alfresco are you using?

Comment: You need to look in to the NavigationBean class and loginBean.

Comment: I want the change to apply on alfresco Explorer "web client"